# After exceeding the retry limit of a self asserted step policy redirecting to an error page. How to stop this redirection and show a custom massage

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have set retry limit(**setting.retryLimit**) for a self asserted step and after exceeding the retry limit policy is redirecting to an error page. Is there any way to stop this redirection and show a custom message instead of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the policy in development mode, it will throw an error on the B2C page and this is not customisable. Otherwise it will send an error back to the application, where the app should display the correct error page itself.

Comment: How to check that is in development mode? DeploymentMode="Development" attribute for "TrustFrameworkPolicy"?

Comment: Yes that right. Remove that line or set to Production instead.